# Tell typescript that this property is a subclass for this variable

Tags: typescript, inheritance

I made an class in typescript that is called "Favoris".
This class has a property "Document", which type is also a class. 
I made another class "PDFDocument" that is a subclass of "Document".

```
export class Favoris {
    Document: Document = null;
    ...
}

export class Document{
    ...
}

export class Form extends Document{
    Fields: any[];
    ...
}
```

I am in a file where, in the context, I know that favoris.Document is type of Form. Is there a way to tell typescript that, in this variable, Document is a Form, so I can always access Form's properties without typing :

```
(<Form> myFav.Document).Fields = [];
```

EDIT ---

I implemented a generic type as suggested by Dario García moya, it works better but In variable affectation I still have trouble :

```
let favoris: Favoris<Document>;
myComponent.favoris = favoris;
```

this affectation is underlined as red because favoris in myComponent is of type "Favoris(form)". I tried this

```
if(favoris instanceof Favoris<Form>)
```

but it doesn't work. the only case where I don't have error is when I do

```
myComponent.favoris = <Favoris<Form>>favoris;
```

I can do this, it is better than before but I still have to force type when variable affectation. Is it the right way to do it or did I do domething wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can always specify the type of a variable with

```
(myFav.Document as Form).Fields = [];
```

Although this is considered more as a hack than good code. You might consider use generic types i.e.

```
export class Favoris<T extends Document> {
    Document: T = null;
    ...
}

export class Document{
    ...
}

export class Form extends Document{
    Fields: any[];
    ...
}
```

then

```
const myFav = new Favoris<Form>();

myFav.Document.Fields = [];
```

I hope this helps.

So in regards of the second part of your question, i wrote an example of something that could work

```
export class Document{
}

export class Favoris<T extends Document> {
    document: T;

    constructor(document: T) {
      this.document = document;
    }
}


export class Form extends Document{
    fields: any[];

    constructor(fields: any[]) {
      super();
      this.fields = fields;
    }
}

class Component<T> {
  favoris: Favoris<T>;

  constructor(favoris: Favoris<T>) {
    this.favoris = favoris;
  }
}

const fiels = ['field1', 'field2'];
const form = new Form(fiels);
form.fields;
const myComponent = new Component(new Favoris(form));

myComponent.favoris.document.fields;
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Hello, thanks for your response, I know I can declare Document as any, but I don't have validation anymore (like if I use a property that doesn't exist neither in Document neither in form)

Comment: Hi, Yes i know but i am not suggestion the use of `any`. Did you try with the Generic type? or with the first proposal?

Greetings

Comment: Ah ok ! I thank a generic type was the same of "any" and It works well ! thanks ! It's just everytime I have to use the "Favoris" object, I have to precise "Favoris<Document>". Is there a way to tell typescript that generally this is a document or whatever but sometimes I know this is a form ?

Comment: I have an error with generic type, there is code so I made an edit to my post

Comment: Hello, thanks for it ! sadly mycomponent must absolutely be a "form" (in this case it can't be a Document) and I am trying to affect the variable of mycomponent, I never instantiate mycomponent manually

Comment: I actually made another question for the second part because you gave the first one a satisfying answer, you can find it here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58911095/check-instanceof-generic-type-in-typescriptionic-to-assign-a-variable

Comment: Thanks! i ll take a look!